# Web Api 2 routing issue with special characters in URL

Tags: c#, rest, email, url, asp.net-web-api2

In the middle of developing a Web Api 2 REST service, we have discovered a routing problem. The endpoint is as follows:

.../{email}/...

The problem is that the email could contain special characters such as '+', which results in a 404 resource not found.

We would really like for the user of the service, to be able to specify the email in the URL. But since the email also legally can contain an '&', this can't just be moved to an URL parameter. How would we go about solving this?

Regards
Frederik

Comment: how about using encoded email, and decode it back on serverside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UrlEncodeUnicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencodeunicode.aspx) and [UrlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx) should be helpfull in your case.

Comment: For anyone wondering, we ended up using the UrlEncode and UrlDecode from the HttpUtility class

Comment: I have a similar problem and UrlEncode/UrlDecode don't seem to help. The string in my URL isn't an email. It's a user-defined name for an object. The problem case includes periods like 'A.E. Milne'. The UrlEncode encodes the space to a + character, but leaves the periods alone and I still get a 404. If I try the same URL without the periods, it works fine. Routing doesn't seem to like them, but UrlEncode doesn't encode them.

Answer (score 2):

No, encoding and deconding can only work if yyou're in control of the client and server operations. If otherwise, the best way is to call the endpoint as such

www.yourwebsite.com/api/account/create?email='{email with any characters}'