# How to encode/decode url strings in an UWP App

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-web-api, uwp

I'm building a UWP App which communicates with a Web-Api. At some Point I'm sending a string in the url to the Web-Api which can be manipulated by the user. Because of that the string can include characters which could do evil things to the Web-Api.
For example:
This is my UserController

```
[Route("api/user/{uid}")]
public User GetUser(string uid)
{
   return userRepository.GetByUid(uid);
}
```

For the sake of this example we assume that the user can put in the `uid` manually in a textbox. Now if he puts in

```
../vipuser
```

He could have access to the VipUserController. Because the `../` goes one hirachy up.

I searched a little and found [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171270/web-api-2-routing-issue-with-special-characters-in-url) which recommends the use of `System.Web.UrlEncodeUnicode` and `System.Web.UrlDecode`.

But since UWP Apps doesn't include the `System.Web` namespace I was wondering if there is an alternative to this methods, which I can use into a UWP-App?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Uri.EscapeDataString()` and `Uri.UnescapeDataString()` will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode` and `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode` over the methods on `Uri`.

This is because `WebUtility` handles space ( ) and plus (+) consistently across both "multipart/form-data" and "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encodings.