# C# Httpclient FormUrlEncodedContent Encoding

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

I have an issue of using httpclient to post data to server.It works well of the httpClient.PostAsync with FormUrlEncodedContent.

However, if my content of FormUrlEncodedContent contains a charater of "~", it does not convert it as %7E. I have no idea how I can force it to encode it.

The following is my current example of the coding.

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    ["content"] = "Hello World~"
});
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
```

The Fiddler raw result of the body content will be:

content=Hello%20World~

It is not my expected. I expect the result should be
content=Hello%20World%7E

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is interesting. So  tilde (~) is very special… if you look at the rfc2396 and rfc3986 it is actually allowed in the URL. rfc1738 defined it as %7e, but rfc2396 and rfc3986 kind of overrule that.

So…this is basically dependent on the encoding implementation. For example PHP changed it at some point: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Btw. in the CoreFx repo you can take a look at the source code of [FormUrlEncodedContent](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/FormUrlEncodedContent.cs)

As you see it uses [Uri.EscapeDataString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx)

And it states that

> By default, the EscapeDataString method converts all characters except
>   for RFC 2396 unreserved characters to their hexadecimal
>   representation.

And in [RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) tilde is defined as an unreserved character.

So this works according to the documentation, and what fiddler shows you is an absolutely valid URL.

To your specific  question to get %7e instead of '~':
One option is to replace it manually, since this is really a special case.

Another one is to use [System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which encodes it to %7e. The difference between EscapeDataString (which is used by FormUrlEncodedContent) and System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode is that EscapeDataString uses as many plaintext characters as possible. But both of them create a valid URL encoded string.

Comment: Thanks it works. I use the source code of the corefx one and create my own class. In the method of Encode. I just need to replace the ~ as %7E.
<code>
        private static string Encode(string data)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }

            // Escape spaces as '+'.
            return Uri.EscapeDataString(data).Replace("%20", "+").Replace("~", "%7E");
        }

Comment: @Jobria yes, that seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around that should do the job:

```
        var formParams = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
            ["content"] = "Hello World~"
        };

        var stringFormParams = new Func<IDictionary<string,string>,string>((dic) => {
            string result = "";
            foreach(var param in dic) {
                if (result.Length > 0) { result += "&"; }
                result += param.Key + "=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(param.Value);
            }   
            return result;             
        }).Invoke(formParams); 

        var stringContent = new StringContent(stringFormParams, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        Console.WriteLine(stringContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
```

Output:

```
content=Hello+World%7E
```

Comment: I think this is still works. however I have not tested it. I used the answer of gregkalapos one. Whatever, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use the HttpUtility UrlEncode method, found in the "System.Web" library.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx) for the msdn page.

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(@"~\Hello World");
```

Result:

> %7e%5cUrl%5cHello+World

I've tried and tested it - it correctly replaces the symbols with their correctly encoded counterpart.

Comment: You are correct - apologies, I didn't see the netcore tag.  @gregkalapos has a good answer there.  Uri.EscapeDataString works nicely all by itself - tried it out using a netcore console app and a netcore web service.

Answer (score 0):

@gregkalapos and @Bertie have a wonderful answers.

But I have other way to encoding by use Uri.

```
Uri.EscapeDataString(str)
```

If you need unescape ,please use `Uri.UnescapeDataString(str)`

See:[How to encode/decode url strings in an UWP App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316154/how-to-encode-decode-url-strings-in-an-uwp-app)

[image]

Comment: but that has the problem if there is non-English character(such as Chinese or janpanese) on the content

Comment: @Jobria It can be use to Chinese character and Japanese character for I use it well.